# Clarification on module structure over matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R-$module. I know that to make $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R^n,R^m)$ an $R-$module I need $R$ to be commutative. However, if we consider $R^{n\times m }$, we can give it $R-$module structure using the usual sum of matrices and scalar multiplication, independently of $R$ being commutative.

But, I find it strange that we can define a module structure in one space and not in the other as there is a natural way to think of a matrix as a morphism. So, my question is if there is a reason why the module structure on matrices needs the ring to be commutative.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary for $R$ to be commutative to make the hom set a module. There are a couple structures on it that are very natural **provided** the modules you're working with are bimodules -- as is the case with $R^n$.

If $R,S,T$ are rings and $A$ is an $S,R$ bimodule and $B$ is an $T,R$ bimodule, then

$\mathrm{Hom}(A_R, B_R)$ has a natural right $S$ module structure using the rule $(f\cdot s)(x):=f(sx)$ and natural left $T$ module structure using the rule $(t\cdot f)(x):=tf(x)$. In fact, the hom set is a $T, S$ bimodule.

In particular, you can have $R=S=T$.

Since $R^n$ is an $R,R$ bimodule for any $n$, you can apply this always to $\mathrm{Hom}(R^n_R, R^m_R)$, which is the same thing as matrices over $R$.

But it is true that given arbitrary one-sided modules $A_R$, $B_R$ with no further information, there is not enough to build these two actions and the best one can say is that the hom set is an abelian group.

---

If you are thinking of left $R$ modules instead, everything can be mirrored: if $A$ is an $R,S$ bimodule and $B$ is an $R,T$ bimodule then $\mathrm{Hom}(_RA, _RB)$ gains a natural $S,T$ bimodule structure via $(s\cdot f\cdot t)(x):=f(xt)s$. This is left $R$ linear because $(s\cdot f\cdot t)(rx)=f(rxt)s=rf(xt)s=r(s\cdot f\cdot t)(x)$

Comment: But, the left action that you define doesn't work $t \cdot f$ is not a $R-$module morphism.

Comment: @rschwieb An $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi$ needs to satisfy $\varphi(rm) = r \varphi(m)$ for all $r \in R$ and $m \in M$. Try showing that $t f$ satisfies this and you'll see why you need $R$ to be commutative.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn You reversed sides of the homomorphisms in question. The suggestion does not apply to what I wrote.  You can find the exposition for this in Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*. One does not need commutativity, although it is convenient when you want all your modules to be bimodules.

Comment: @Johanna $(t\cdot f)(xr):=tf(xr) = tf(x)r=(t\cdot f)(x) r$. So $t\cdot f$ is right $R$ linear. What is "not working"?

Comment: Ok, I should have clarified that in the question I was thinking about left modules.

Comment: @Johanna OK that's fine. Everything I said can be mirrored. Added a blurb.

Comment: @rschwieb I see, $R$ is acting on the right in your second paragraph. My mistake.